# What am I doing wrong in the following WebGL code?

Tags: webgl

I started from an example WebGL program that shows a single cube on the page. The example code does not use classes.

I want to be able to draw multiple cubes that can move independently. So I added a "Cube" class. Each instance of this class uses its own "program". I create two objects, but I draw only the first one. Unfortunately the later instantiated object is shown instead. E.g. in the code below "ground" is shown instead of "cube1".

Relevant parts of the code is below. Can you see any problem with it? How can I fix it?

```
...
////
class Cube {
  constructor(gl, color) {
    this.gl = gl;
    this.program = initShaders(gl, "vertex-shader", "fragment-shader");

    //// Model buffers and attributes
    [this.pointsArray, this.colorsArray] = cubePointsAndColors(color);
    this.numVertices = 36;
    this.initAttributeBuffers();

    //// Camera Related Uniforms Matrices
    this.modelViewMatrixLoc = gl.getUniformLocation(
      this.program,
      "modelViewMatrix"
    );
    this.projectionMatrixLoc = gl.getUniformLocation(
      this.program,
      "projectionMatrix"
    );
  }

  draw() {
    this.gl.drawArrays(this.gl.TRIANGLES, 0, this.numVertices);
  }

  initAttributeBuffers() {
    // arrange cube color data stuff
    var cBuffer = this.gl.createBuffer();
    this.gl.bindBuffer(this.gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, cBuffer);
    this.gl.bufferData(
      this.gl.ARRAY_BUFFER,
      flatten(this.colorsArray),
      this.gl.STATIC_DRAW
    );
    var vColor = this.gl.getAttribLocation(this.program, "vColor");
    this.gl.vertexAttribPointer(vColor, 4, this.gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
    this.gl.enableVertexAttribArray(vColor);

    // arrange cube vertex data stuff
    var vBuffer = this.gl.createBuffer();
    this.gl.bindBuffer(this.gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vBuffer);
    this.gl.bufferData(
      this.gl.ARRAY_BUFFER,
      flatten(this.pointsArray),
      this.gl.STATIC_DRAW
    );
    var vPosition = this.gl.getAttribLocation(this.program, "vPosition");
    this.gl.vertexAttribPointer(vPosition, 4, this.gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
    this.gl.enableVertexAttribArray(vPosition);
  }
}

window.onload = function init() {
  //// initialize WebGl System
  const canvas = document.getElementById("gl-canvas");
  const gl = WebGLUtils.setupWebGL(canvas);
  if (!gl) {
    alert("WebGL isn't available");
  }
  gl.viewport(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  aspect = canvas.width / canvas.height;
  gl.clearColor(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
  gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);

  //// Initialize game objects
  var cube1 = new Cube(gl, vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0));
  var ground = new Cube(gl, vec4(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0));
  let gameObjects = [cube1];

  // sliders for viewing parameters
  readGUI();

  render(gl, gameObjects);
};

////
var render = function(gl, gameObjects) {
  //// clear the background
  gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

  //// camera settings
  eye = vec3(
    radius * Math.sin(theta) * Math.cos(phi),
    radius * Math.sin(theta) * Math.sin(phi),
    radius * Math.cos(theta)
  );
  modelViewMatrix = lookAt(eye, at, up);
  projectionMatrix = perspective(fovy, aspect, near, far);

  //// draw all objects
  for (let objectI = 0; objectI < gameObjects.length; objectI++) {
    const gameObject = gameObjects[objectI];

    gl.useProgram(gameObject.program);

    gl.uniformMatrix4fv(
      gameObject.modelViewMatrixLoc,
      false,
      flatten(modelViewMatrix)
    );
    gl.uniformMatrix4fv(
      gameObject.projectionMatrixLoc,
      false,
      flatten(projectionMatrix)
    );
    gameObject.draw();
  }

  requestAnimFrame(() => render(gl, gameObjects));
};
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In WebGL 1.0 `drawArrays`, uses the vertices which are currently specified by `vertexAttribPointer` and enabled by `enableVertexAttribArray`.

Use properties to store the buffer objects (`this.cBuffer`, `this.vBuffer`) and attribute indices (`this.vColor`, `this.vPosition`):

```js
initAttributeBuffers() {
    // arrange cube color data stuff
    this.cBuffer = this.gl.createBuffer();
    this.gl.bindBuffer(this.gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, this.cBuffer);
    this.gl.bufferData(
        this.gl.ARRAY_BUFFER,
        flatten(this.colorsArray),
        this.gl.STATIC_DRAW
    );
    this.vColor = this.gl.getAttribLocation(this.program, "vColor");

    // arrange cube vertex data stuff
    this.vBuffer = this.gl.createBuffer();
    this.gl.bindBuffer(this.gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, this.vBuffer);
    this.gl.bufferData(
        this.gl.ARRAY_BUFFER,
        flatten(this.pointsArray),
        this.gl.STATIC_DRAW
    );
    this.vPosition = this.gl.getAttribLocation(this.program, "vPosition");
}
```

Specify and enable the arrays of generic vertex attribute data right before the draw call:

```js
draw() {
    this.gl.bindBuffer(this.gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, this.cBuffer);
    this.gl.vertexAttribPointer(this.vColor, 4, this.gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
    this.gl.enableVertexAttribArray(this.vColor);

    this.gl.bindBuffer(this.gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, this.vBuffer);
    this.gl.vertexAttribPointer(this.vPosition, 4, this.gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
    this.gl.enableVertexAttribArray(this.vPosition);

    this.gl.drawArrays(this.gl.TRIANGLES, 0, this.numVertices);
}
```

---

In WebGL 2.0 (or by the use of the extension [*OES_vertex_array_object*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/OES_vertex_array_object)), that can be simplified by the use of  [WebGLVertexArrayObject](https://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/specs/latest/2.0/#3.6)s.

The vertex specification is stated in the vertex array object:

```js
initAttributeBuffers() {
    // create vertex array object
    this.vao = this.gl.createVertexArray();
    this.gl.bindVertexArray(this.vao);

    // arrange cube color data stuff
    var cBuffer = this.gl.createBuffer();
    this.gl.bindBuffer(this.gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, cBuffer);
    this.gl.bufferData(
        this.gl.ARRAY_BUFFER,
        flatten(this.colorsArray),
        this.gl.STATIC_DRAW
    );
    var vColor = this.gl.getAttribLocation(this.program, "vColor");
    this.gl.vertexAttribPointer(vColor, 4, this.gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
    this.gl.enableVertexAttribArray(vColor);

    // arrange cube vertex data stuff
    var vBuffer = this.gl.createBuffer();
    this.gl.bindBuffer(this.gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vBuffer);
    this.gl.bufferData(
        this.gl.ARRAY_BUFFER,
        flatten(this.pointsArray),
        this.gl.STATIC_DRAW
    );
    var vPosition = this.gl.getAttribLocation(this.program, "vPosition");
    this.gl.vertexAttribPointer(vPosition, 4, this.gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
    this.gl.enableVertexAttribArray(vPosition);
}
```

It is sufficient to bind the vertex array before the draw call:

```js
draw() {
    this.gl.bindVertexArray(this.vao);
    this.gl.drawArrays(this.gl.TRIANGLES, 0, this.numVertices);
}
```